# Using for loops when editing the direct source

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wrote some game code well before es6 came out and all it's beneficial functions came out such as `reduce, map, filter, forEach` etc.

Many times in my game code I use a traditional `for` loop and doing many inner `for` loops in order to change a setting. Could I do the same thing with the following code with any of these newer functions such as `reduce`?

```js
var i;
for (i = 0; i < gameData.inventoryBox.length; i++) {
  if (gameData.inventoryBox[i].ID == param1) {
    var k;
    for (k = 0; k < gameData.inventoryBox[i].toDoListDetails.lists.length; k++) {
      if (gameData.inventoryBox[i].toDoListDetails.lists[k].id == param2) {
        var x;
        for (x = 0; x < gameData.inventoryBox[i].toDoListDetails.lists[k].items.length; x++) {
          if (gameData.inventoryBox[i].toDoListDetails.lists[k].items[x].id == param3) {
            gameData.inventoryBox[i].toDoListDetails.lists[k].items[x].status = param4;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

From most use case scenerios that I have seen, `reduce` is only beneficial if you are making new arrays of data rather than amending the direct source, in this case "gameData".
Am I better off sticking with what I already have here?

Comment: _"...such as `reduce, map, filter, forEach`"_ - They are all part of ES5

Comment: If your ids are unique then (you're missing some `break`s) you could use `.find()`

Comment: Hmm intially they won't be unique ids, but I could make them. Please could you provide an example?

Comment: `var i;` and `for (i = 0; i < gameData.inventoryBox.length; i++)` could have been `for (var i = 0; i < gameData.inventoryBox.length; i++)`, and at the same time those dreadful `gameData.inventoryBox[i].toDoListDetails.lists[k].<anything>`-s should have been `listItem.<anything>` via having useful variable declaration lines (starting with `gameData.inventoryBox`), that's not even a matter of ES version but programming in a readable way. Generally this question is too subjective here, it would have a better place on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably chain filters and forEaches to test for the conditions. It'd be something like this:

```
gameData.inventoryBox
    .filter(a => a.ID == param1)
    .forEach(x => {
        x.toDoListDetails.lists
            .filter(b => b.id == param2)
            .forEach(y => {
                y.items
                    .filter(c => c.id == params3)
                    .forEach(z => {
                        z.status = param4;
                    }
            }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Shouldn't I be using find instead of filter? Since there are unique ids per array - for the 3 individual arrays.

Comment: I thought you had duplicate id's per your comment to the question. Either way, this code would work for both cases (with a small coefficient-level performance difference though).

Comment: Ah sorry I meant there could be similar ids across arrays inventoryBox, lists and items, but not in the individual array such as inventoryBox. Cool thanks, it seems forEach has a slightly slower processing speed compared with for?

Comment: That's a good point. However, I would assume the nature of this question is to transform some old code into something more modern, readable, and maintainable. Your original code is likely to be more efficient, but it's definitely harder to read. It really boils down to how optimized you need your code to be. I've read that forEach's are also optimized by browsers in some cases, might worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this forEach loop

```
gameData.inventoryBox.forEach((inventory) => {
  if(inventory.id === param1){
    item.toDoListDetails.lists.forEach(list => {
      if(list.id === param2){
        list.items.forEach(item => {
          if(item === param3){
            item.status = param4
          }
        })
      }
    })
  }
})
```